# GCM Notification when battery saver is turned on

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, battery-saver

I have one doubt regarding battery saver. How GCM Notification behaves when battery saver is turned on? Whether GCM Notification with normal priority will be delivered to the app?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to Doze mode (https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) then only high priority notifications will be sent (which btw is the default for FCM `notification messages`  messages....default for `data messages` is normal priority)...more info at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: No I am not referring to doze mode. When we enable batterysaver, background data will be disabled for all the apps. But I see some apps like Signal and Hangouts are able to receive messages when app is in background.

Comment: @KrishnaM: were you able to fix this issue? I'm in a similar situation and need a solution.